# Population of dropdown showing no data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have wrote a script where i need to populate a dropdown based on selection of another dropdown using j-query, but when i select the first dropdown the other dropdown is showing no data,please help pardon me if i went wrong somewhere.!

**script.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select id="json-one" class="form-control">  
     <option selected="" value="base">Please Select</option>  
     <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>  
     <option value="Engineer">Engineer</option>  
     <option value="Lawyer">Lawyer</option>  
    </select> 
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <select id="json-two" class="form-control">  
        <option>Please choose from above</option>  
    </select>  
</div>


<script>
    var data = {
"Doctor":"General,specilist",
"Engineer":"Computers,electronic"
"Lawyer":"Civil,Criminal"
};
$("#json-one").change(function() {

                var $dropdown = $(this);

                //$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {

                    var key = $dropdown.val();
                    var vals = [];

                    switch(key) {
                        case 'Doctor':
                            vals = data.Doctor.split(",");
                            break;
                        case 'Engineer':
                            vals = data.Engineer.split(",");
                            break;
                        case 'Lawyer':
                            vals = data.Lawyer.split(",");
                            break;
                        case 'base':
                            vals = ['Please choose from above'];
                    }

                    var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
                    $jsontwo.empty();
                    $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
                        $jsontwo.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
                    //});

                });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: Is vals populated properly? DId you console log?

Comment: Have you found where everything goes wrong? Is the change function triggering? Do you have the correct dropdowns after you select them? Does the json return from the server? Does the json contain the right data? Does vals contain the right data after the switch? Does the loop to append trigger?

Comment: Yes i did check its giving out valid json data ..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Code should work fine but you need to care for 2 things.

1: You should have a data.json file.

2: the JSON object in data.json should have the same structure as you are consuming it in the success callback of the get JSON

```
{
  "beverages": "coke,pepsi",
  "snacks":"chips,biscuit"
}
```

you can see it working in the below plunker.

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/2dI09RIDuFGc9XMKXU1h?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the same code as yours in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nitinj_n/3tLh9njr/) fiddle.

The only difference is I am not loading json asynchronously. So you need to check the loading of json part, or whether file is present at the location or not.

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <select id="json-one" class="form-control">  
        <option selected="" value="base">Please Select</option>  
        <option value="beverages">Beverages</option>  
        <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>  
    </select>  
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <select id="json-two" class="form-control">  
        <option>Please choose from above</option>  
    </select>  
</div>

var data = {
"beverages":"tea,coffee",
"snacks":"namkeen,biscuits"
};
$("#json-one").change(function() {

                var $dropdown = $(this);

                //$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {

                    var key = $dropdown.val();
                    var vals = [];

                    switch(key) {
                        case 'beverages':
                            vals = data.beverages.split(",");
                            break;
                        case 'snacks':
                            vals = data.snacks.split(",");
                            break;
                        case 'base':
                            vals = ['Please choose from above'];
                    }

                    var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
                    $jsontwo.empty();
                    $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
                        $jsontwo.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
                    //});

                });
            });
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: sir thanks for useful answer..i have up dated my code on same bases but sadly its not working as i was..!!

Comment: @Ninja : Asynchronous call will not matter here as the  data is accessed in the success callback of the getJSON function and it will only execute once the JSON data is received.